# Low-level implementation of generics

Tags: c#, generics

If I have this:

```
class Pair<T> {}

class Animal {}
class Human {}
```

and then:

```
Pair<Animal> a = new Pair<Animal>();
Pair<Human> h = new Pair<Human>();
```

I read that the CLR creates only one time a specialized version of `Pair` where
`T` is replaced by `object`. After when `h` is created it reused that version.

But I don't understand what does this meaning. How can it knows in a type-safe manner when `object` is an `Animal` type and when it is an `Human` type?

What does it meaning the word "**reused**"?

Comment: Where did you read that?  I think we need to understand the context to know what that author meant by "reused".

Comment: Type safety is checked both by the C# compiler and by the jitter.  After which the type no longer matters, an object reference is simply a pointer at runtime.  Since Human and Animal objects are plain pointers at runtime, the exact same machine code can be used for both.  You can still get more than one version of the code, happens when a T is a value type.  Now it isn't just a plain pointer anymore so sharing code can no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

No - that's how Java does it - it checks when compiling that the right type is being used, but under the hood, everything is just a `Pair<object>`.

C# is much better because it creates a genuine new type each time. Why is this approach better? Because you can find out the type at runtime using reflection (something you can't do in Java)

You can see this if you get the IL generated - you can see the unique types:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery<UserQuery+Animal>+Pair`1..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0007:  newobj      UserQuery<UserQuery+Human>+Pair`1..ctor
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // h
IL_000D:  ret         

Pair`1..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret         

Animal..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret         

Human..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

Comment: No, the CLR does re-use the representation of generic types for reference type parameters. It only needs to generate a new representation for value types which are different sizes. It still retains the generic types are runtime though, unlike Java. It also questionable whether reified generics are 'better' than using erasure.

Comment: But also in C# reference types are replaced by object but this is done at run-time http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx. Your code shows IL where type parameters are not replaced but the CLR does that replacement.

Comment: @Lee Interesting, I didn't know that. I think for practical purposes my answer is useful though so I'll leave it up, but that's some interesting info. Is there a scenario where that distinction becomes relevant though (as it sounds like it's purely a performance optimization, with no impact on the language itself, if I've understood correctly?)

Comment: No there is no scenario but my question is only to better understand how generics works. However, IMHO, you answer is not correct. It answers incorrectly to what I'm asking.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question then - what the CLR does isn't really relevant in the "real" world (i.e. the world of C#). Are you asking something like "What is preventing me from adding a `Human` to a `List<Animal>` using reflection"?

Comment: I don't think it concerns C# directly in any way, but it's quite a significant performance optimisation since otherwise there would be an enormous explosion of type definitions at runtime when generic types are instantiated. I think this question is asking how the CLR is able to re-use class and method definitions for generic types and methods with reference type parameters. It's possible because references are all the same size and calls to reference type members are done uniformly through the receiver reference which knows its own type.

Answer (score 0):

> How can it knows in a type-safe manner when object is an Animal type and when it is an Human type?

You can't, at least not from within the `Pair` class.  Now *outside* of the `Pair` class you know based on the declaration of the type:

```
class Pair<T> {
    public T Value {get; set;}  // the compiler has no idea what the type of `T` is at compile-time
}

Pair<Animal> a = new Pair<Animal>();
a.Value = new Animal();   // here the compiler knows that `Value` is an `Animal` based on the declared type of `a`.
```